# Chartjs Stacked bar graph with forEach for labels

Tags: javascript, foreach, chart.js, spring-thymeleaf, stacked-bar-chart

sorry if this has been answered already but I cant figure how to include labels in my for each. Im getting my data from spring boot with the data called 'employees' and there is 20 something employees in the 'employees' data. I loop through and add the employee names to the x axis and the personMonths to the y axis. Each employee has a project, sometimes an employee has more than one project. I managed to get a stacked bar graph working. The Spring/thymeleaf data looks like this, this is one employee with 4 projects:

````
    const employees = [
    {"name":"Nat","contractFrom":"01.4.2022","contractTo":"01.3.2025","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"4","monthTo":"12","personMonths":9.0,"employee":null,"empty":false}]
      },
      {"name":"Kate","contractFrom":"01.7.2021","contractTo":"No date entered","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"11","monthTo":"12","personMonths":2.0,"employee":null,"empty":false
    },{"projectId":"87141502","projectName":"Project9","startDate":"10/22","endDate":"10/22","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"10","personMonths":10.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
    },
      {"name":"Adam","contractFrom":"15.07.2021","contractTo":"14.07.2024","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"12","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":false
    },                                                                                             {"projectId":"87141502","projectName":"Project9","startDate":"10/22","endDate":"10/22","monthFrom":"9","monthTo":"9","personMonths":1.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241516","projectName":"Project12","startDate":"05/22","endDate":"04/25","monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"12","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project16","startDate":"10/19","endDate":"09/22","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"8","personMonths":8.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Dan","contractFrom":"01.8.2021","contractTo":"01.7.2024","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"12","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":false},{"projectId":"61241513","projectName":"Project8","startDate":"01/22","endDate":"03/23","monthFrom":"5","monthTo":"12","personMonths":8.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project16","startDate":"10/19","endDate":"09/22","monthFrom":"6","monthTo":"9","personMonths":4.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"John","contractFrom":"01.3.2022","contractTo":"01.4.2025","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"8","monthTo":"12","personMonths":5.0,"employee":null,"empty":false},{"projectId":"61241515","projectName":"Project13","startDate":"09/22","endDate":"08/25","monthFrom":"9","monthTo":"12","personMonths":4.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project16","startDate":"10/19","endDate":"09/22","monthFrom":"3","monthTo":"8","personMonths":6.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Frank","contractFrom":"01.6.2022","contractTo":"01.7.2025","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"12","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":false},{"projectId":"61241513","projectName":"Project8","startDate":"01/22","endDate":"03/23","monthFrom":"6","monthTo":"9","personMonths":4.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"612415","projectName":"Project21","startDate":"08/21","endDate":"07/25","monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"12","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Mic","contractFrom":"","contractTo":"No date entered","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"3","personMonths":1.5,"employee":null,"empty":false},{"projectId":"61741501","projectName":"Project4","startDate":"10/21","endDate":"09/22","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"9","personMonths":4.5,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61641502","projectName":"Project5","startDate":"04/22","endDate":"09/22","monthFrom":"4","monthTo":"9","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Michael","contractFrom":"01.11.2021","contractTo":"01.10.2024","projects":[{"projectId":"61241513","projectName":"Project8","startDate":"01/22","endDate":"03/23","monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"12","personMonths":3.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Mia","contractFrom":"01.5.2022","contractTo":"01.10.2023","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"5","monthTo":"12","personMonths":8.0,"employee":null,"empty":false}]
      },
      {"name":"Wendy","contractFrom":"15.11.2021","contractTo":"14.11.2024","projects":[{"projectId":"61341508","projectName":"Project3","startDate":"01/22","endDate":"12/24","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"12","personMonths":12.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Rina","contractFrom":"15.09.2021","contractTo":"01.5.2022","projects":[{"projectId":"61141504","projectName":"Project11","startDate":"12/22","endDate":"12/22","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"5","personMonths":5.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Luke","contractFrom":"15.01.2022","contractTo":"15.04.2023","projects":[{"projectId":"61241512","projectName":"Project6","startDate":"01/22","endDate":"03/23","monthFrom":"0","monthTo":"12","personMonths":11.5,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Harry","contractFrom":"01.12.2020","contractTo":"01.5.2025","projects":[{"projectId":"61241514","projectName":"Project7","startDate":"01/22","endDate":"03/23","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"12","personMonths":12.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Bill","contractFrom":"01.4.2021","contractTo":"01.3.2025","projects":[{"projectId":"61241509","projectName":"Project17","startDate":"10/20","endDate":"09/23","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"12","personMonths":12.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Zane","contractFrom":"01.4.2021","contractTo":"01.3.2025","projects":[{"projectId":"87441507","projectName":"Project14","startDate":"10/22","endDate":" 04/2024","monthFrom":"11","monthTo":"12","personMonths":2.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61341507","projectName":"Project15","startDate":"01/19","endDate":"06/22?","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"4","personMonths":4.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project16","startDate":"10/19","endDate":"09/22","monthFrom":"5","monthTo":"9","personMonths":5.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241509","projectName":"Project17","startDate":"10/20","endDate":"09/23","monthFrom":"10","monthTo":"10","personMonths":1.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project18","startDate":"03/21","endDate":"10/23","monthFrom":"3","monthTo":"4","personMonths":2.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Barry","contractFrom":"01.3.2021","contractTo":"01.3.2023","projects":[{"projectId":"13415000","projectName":"Project1","startDate":null,"endDate":null,"monthFrom":"9","monthTo":"12","personMonths":4.0,"employee":null,"empty":false},                                                       {"projectId":"87141503","projectName":"Project10","startDate":"10/22","endDate":"10/22","monthFrom":"3","monthTo":"8","personMonths":6.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},{"projectId":"61141504","projectName":"Project11","startDate":"12/22","endDate":"12/22","monthFrom":"7.0","monthTo":"12","personMonths":6.0,"employee":null,"empty":false}]
      },
      {"name":"Nigel","contractFrom":"15.04.2021","contractTo":"01.4.2022","projects":[{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project18","startDate":"03/21","endDate":"10/23","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"4","personMonths":4.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Tony","contractFrom":"01.10.2021","contractTo":"01.9.2024","projects":[{"projectId":"61141504","projectName":"Project11","startDate":"12/22","endDate":"12/22","monthFrom":"8","monthTo":"9","personMonths":2.0,"employee":null,"empty":true},                                                   {"projectId":"61241511","projectName":"Project20","startDate":"06/21","endDate":"05/25","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"10.0","personMonths":10.0,"employee":null,"empty":false}]
      },
      {"name":"Ross","contractFrom":"15.12.2021","contractTo":"15.12.2024","projects":[{"projectId":"87141506","projectName":"Project19","startDate":"03/21","endDate":"02/25","monthFrom":"1","monthTo":"12","personMonths":12.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Ray","contractFrom":"15.06.2022","contractTo":"01.10.2023","projects":[{"projectId":"61241510","projectName":"Project18","startDate":"03/21","endDate":"10/23","monthFrom":"5","monthTo":"12","personMonths":8.0,"employee":null,"empty":true}]
      },
      {"name":"Colin","contractFrom":"","contractTo":"No date entered","projects":[]}
    ];```
    
    [Here is my graph][1]
    
    What Im after is to have the project names above where the 'project months' is hard coded at the top. Also if possible different colours for different projects. Here is my code, please help, many thanks.
    ```
    
    
        var employeeData = [];
            employees.forEach(function(empl){
                empl.projects.forEach(function(employeeProject) {
                    var names = employeeProject.projectName;
                var employee = {x: empl.name, y: employeeProject.personMonths};
                employeeData.push(employee);
    
                })
        })
    
        const labelChart = 'Person Months'
    
    // setup
        const data = {
    //      labels: ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'],
          datasets: [{
            label: 'project months',
            data: employeeData,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(235, 56, 56, 0.4)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255, 26, 104, 1)'
          }]
        };
    
        // config
        const config = {
          type: 'bar',
          data,
          options: {
            scales: {
              y: {
                beginAtZero: true
              }
            },
            plugins: {
                tooltip: {
                    yAlign: 'bottom',
                    titleMarginBottom: 0
                }
            }
          }
        };
    
        // render init block
        const myChart = new Chart(
          document.getElementById('myChart'),
          config
        );
````

[Updated graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdfdN.png)
[Another Image with codepen data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpGax.png)

```
{
  name: 'John Smith', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 1.0
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Bob Kennedy', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 2.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0002', 
    projectName: 'Project 2', 
    startDate: '10/22', 
    endDate: '10/22', 
    monthFrom: '3', 
    monthTo: '8', 
    personMonths: 3.0
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Kevin Red', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 4.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0002', 
    projectName: 'Project 2', 
    startDate: '10/22', 
    endDate: '10/22', 
    monthFrom: '3', 
    monthTo: '8', 
    personMonths: 5.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0003', 
    projectName: 'Project 3', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 6.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0004', 
    projectName: 'Project 4', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 7.0
  }]
},
  {
  name: 'James Brown', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 8.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0002', 
    projectName: 'Project 2', 
    startDate: '10/22', 
    endDate: '10/22', 
    monthFrom: '3', 
    monthTo: '8', 
    personMonths: 9.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0003', 
    projectName: 'Project 3', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 10.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0004', 
    projectName: 'Project 4', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 11.0
  }]
}
];
```

**EDIT**
So what if I had 2 chunks of the same project in the one year? Below is an image where Employee Luke Sky has 2 chunks of 'Test Project' and is console.logged but in the bar graph for him you can see he is missing the 2nd 6.5 month chunk.
[image]
Both chunks
[image]

Comment: You could create another array for labels and populate it from `projectName`s in the same `forEach`.

Comment: Thanks for replying so quick, I did do that but its not working for me. So basically I did the same as ```employeeData = []```, but did ```projectNames = []```, then inside the forEach did ```projectNames.push(employeeProject.projectName);```. Then in datasets I did ```label: projectNames``` but that didnt put any labels and the hover over label has every single project name in there. Do you mind giving an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, I think you could create the `labels` for the chart getting all employees name.
Then you can extract all datasets getting all projects for employee, setting the `label` as project name, the `data` as an array with all person months of employee (in my example I have got only 4 employees therefore data.length = 4).

See snippet or codepen: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/BaxjwWM

```js
// ------------------
// data to show on te chart
// ------------------
const employees = [
{
  name: 'John Smith', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 1.0
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Bob Kennedy', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 2.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0002', 
    projectName: 'Project 2', 
    startDate: '10/22', 
    endDate: '10/22', 
    monthFrom: '3', 
    monthTo: '8', 
    personMonths: 3.0
  }]
}, {
  name: 'Kevin Red', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 4.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0002', 
    projectName: 'Project 2', 
    startDate: '10/22', 
    endDate: '10/22', 
    monthFrom: '3', 
    monthTo: '8', 
    personMonths: 5.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0003', 
    projectName: 'Project 3', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 6.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0004', 
    projectName: 'Project 4', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 7.0
  }]
},
  {
  name: 'James Brown', 
  contractFrom: '01.3.2021',
  contractTo: '01.3.2023',
  projects: [{
    projectId: '0001', 
    projectName: 'project1', 
    startDate: '9/22', 
    endDate: '8/24', 
    monthFrom: '9', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 8.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0002', 
    projectName: 'Project 2', 
    startDate: '10/22', 
    endDate: '10/22', 
    monthFrom: '3', 
    monthTo: '8', 
    personMonths: 9.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0003', 
    projectName: 'Project 3', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 10.0
  }, {
    projectId: '0004', 
    projectName: 'Project 4', 
    startDate: '12/22', 
    endDate: '12/22', 
    monthFrom: '10', 
    monthTo: '12', 
    personMonths: 11.0
  }]
}];
// ---------------------
// scans all data, creating an array as result with all employees names
// this array represents the "labels" of the scale X
// ---------------------
const labels = employees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  // adds the employee name to the array to return
  result.push(item.name);
  return result;
}, []); // <-- in the reduce, the [] is the initial value of variable "result"
// ---------------------
// random colors generator
// this can be removed and use specific color 
// or other plugins to use series of color
// ---------------------
const randomColorGenerator = function () { 
  return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8); 
};
// ---------------------
// scans all data, creating an object as result with all prjects
// the object has got as property name the ID of the project and as value the dataset object.
// in the chart, 1 dataset is equals to 1 project
// the scan is done for each employee and then for each project of each employee
// the cycle checks if the project is already created for another employee
// ---------------------
const projects = employees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  // scans project
  item.projects.forEach(function(prj){
    // gets project ID 
    const prjId = prj.projectId;
    // checks if already the related dataset is already created
    if (!result[prjId]) {
      // if not, adds to the object the dataset with project ID as property of the object
      result[prjId] = {
        label: prj.projectName, // name of dataset is project name
        data: [], // the data, in this phase, is empty, it will fill afterwards
        backgroundColor: randomColorGenerator()
      };
    }
  });
  return result;
}, {}); // <-- in the reduce, the {} is the initial value of variable "result"
// ---------------------
// scans all data, to fill the datasets (related to the projects) withe data, taken from the data.
// Some employees couldn't have any engagement on some projects therefore 0 is added to the data
// the chart will have the folloing matrix:
// 
// employee | prj1              | prj2              | ... | prjn             |
// emp1     | personMonths or 0 | personMonths or 0 | ... |personMonths or 0 |
// ---------------------
employees.forEach(function(item) {
  // scans all projects previously extracted, againts the employee projects
  for (const prjId of Object.keys(projects)) {
    const prj = projects[prjId];
    // checks if the employee was engaged for this project
    const empPrj = item.projects.filter(el => el.projectId === prjId);
    // if the array is not empty, the the employee was engaged in teh project
    // then adds personMonths the teh data array.
    if (empPrj.length) {
      prj.data.push(empPrj[0].personMonths); 
    } else {
    // if here, the employee wasn't engaged in teh project then add 0.
      prj.data.push(0); 
    }
  }
});

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels, // employees names
    datasets: Object.values(projects)  // projects 
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@3.9.1/dist/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your example is exactly what Im after, unfortunately when I use your code with my data the graph isn't right. I added another image at the bottom of my question (sorry the data is sensitive but I screen shotted what I could). So this code is a bit beyond my skills but from what I can see in your 'employees' data example, the personMonths is a color now, is that right? Before the yaxis data maxed out at 14 months, now its around 130 months. Am I looking at it wrong?

Comment: No, "personMonths" is a number (personMonths:Math.random() * 20. I used a random value. The Y axis is changed because I used the random value. But change the random vaue, i can stay less then 14. But using your real data, should work. From your image, I cannot understand what is wrong. Have a look to the data structure I used about employee. Is the same your are using?

Comment: Im not sure, not sure if this changes things but my personMonths is a double? The data example above is exactly what prints out in the terminal in intellij

Comment: the published code doesn't change personMonths but only read and add it to the data array of the datasets "result[prjId].data.push(prj.personMonths);"

Comment: Do you think it is possible for your to publish the JSON with the data, hiding all sensitive data? you could also reduce the amount of data, leaving only employee name, projects with project id, name and personMonths. only if possible

Comment: I just put my data into codepen and I'm assuming its not json. I had to remove my Java objects: Emplyee and Project and change all equals ```=``` to colons ```:```. So Im assuming I havent got correct json.

Comment: I have seen it, on what you published. In fact I cleaned it to prepare the codepen

Comment: So I converted the data to json using ObjectMapper in java, then put that converted json into codepen and the same happens when I first used your code. So its not the data, I just added extra data to your code pen and I found that it does the same thing with 2 or 3 times more data. Does that explain something? It seems its ok with 3 different employees but as soon as you add more the last columns in the chart are wrong.

Comment: I added another photo of what happens when copying and pasting your data 3 times and adding extra employees and projects.

Comment: I have created a gist with the data you provided in the post and the JSON transformation, used by codepen: https://gist.github.com/stockiNail/085f10852a8f8f56085e046ec89d9d65 Maybe there is something wrong or missing but sounds weird the result of the picture, just adding data

Comment: So I stubbornly went through and changed double quotes to no quote and doubles to singles just to get my data exactly like yours and nothing changes. So I tried to find a pattern using employee1 having 1 project with personMonths 1.0, employee2 having 2 projects with personMonths 2.0 and 3.0, employee3 having 3 projects with personMonths 4.0, 5.0 and 6.0, etc. And the chart changes when using 3 and 4 employees. I put the data above if you want to try, maybe it gives you a clue.

Comment: I think I found the issue... let me take some time to fix codepen and the answer

Comment: I have update the answer and now it should be ok. Also codepen is updated: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/BaxjwWM , using your new data. Let me know if now it works for you as well

Comment: Dude thank you so much, this is awesome. I really appreciate you taking the time.

Comment: Sorry to annoy you again but can you explain what happened? Maybe explain you code a little?

Comment: in the answer or in the codepen? where do you prefer? I could comments on the code

Comment: prob here is better, and update the code. Then its the right answer here.

Comment: updated. Have a look if it's ok for you

Comment: Man so good, thank you again for your time. This would have token me so long to figure out. Legend.

Comment: @ user2057925 Hi again, I'm really sorry to bug you again but I think I found a bug. I added my data again above, it is my data with only employee names and project names changed so its what I have. If you enter it into codepen you can see Project18 doesnt appear for Employees: Zane, Nigel and Ray. Project 16 appears. Sorry Ive been looking at it for 2 days and cant see the problem. In the data Zane has both Project16 and Project18 but only Project16 appears in the bar. He should have 5 different colors. Also what is: "empty":true/false, thats not added by me?

Comment: The procedure is using "projectId" as key of the project object and "Project18" and "Project16" have got the "projectId" and sounds to be a bug of the data. This is why you have got that bug

Comment: If you have those data, you could try to use the "projectName" as key of the projects object instead of "projectId".

Comment: Damn I suck, sorry man. Sorted it.

Comment: Hi again, and sorry again, do you mind having a quick look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74388121/javascript-not-pushing-data-to-the-dataarray

Comment: added answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74388121/javascript-not-pushing-data-to-the-dataarray/74390896#74390896

Comment: Hey again, sorry I have one more question, I've added an **edit**. Can we have 2 chunks of one project for one employee? I've added screen shots.