# Javascript not pushing data to the dataArray

Tags: javascript, json, spring-boot, sorting, chart.js

Im not a javascript guy but I had some help getting my chart working with chart js [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73641695/chartjs-stacked-bar-graph-with-foreach-for-labels/73648771?noredirect=1#comment130179111_73648771), but since then I had to change the data structure from just 2 tables to 3 (with oneToMany - manyToOne). I feel Im pretty close but can I get some help with pushing the employeeProjectMonths to the dataArray?

The listEmployees looks like this:

```
var listEmployees = [
{"id":1,"name":"Bill Turner","contractedFrom":"2022-09-01","contractedTo":"2022-10-30",
"employeeProjects":[
{"id":14,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 7","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":7.7},
{"id":2,"project":{"id":6,"projectNumber":66666,"name":"Project 6","startDate":"2020-10-01","endDate":"2021-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":35.0,"currentBookedMonths":60.0,"remainingBookedMonths":6.0,"numberOfEmployees":6},"employeeBookedMonths":6.0},
{"id":7,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 7","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":8.0},
{"id":5,"project":{"id":9,"projectNumber":56789,"name":"Project 9","startDate":"2020-10-01","endDate":"2021-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":35.0,"currentBookedMonths":30.0,"remainingBookedMonths":5.0,"numberOfEmployees":3},"employeeBookedMonths":8.0},
{"id":15,"project":{"id":8,"projectNumber":54321,"name":"Project 8","startDate":"2020-05-01","endDate":"2022-06-31","projectLengthInMonths":40.0,"currentBookedMonths":32.0,"remainingBookedMonths":8.0,"numberOfEmployees":4},"employeeBookedMonths":8.8}]},

{"id":2,"name":"Kate Miller","contractedFrom":"2022-01-01","contractedTo":"2022-05-30",
"employeeProjects":[
{"id":3,"project":{"id":4,"projectNumber":44444,"name":"Project 4","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":40.0,"remainingBookedMonths":4.0,"numberOfEmployees":4},"employeeBookedMonths":14.0},
{"id":6,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 7","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":5.0},
{"id":8,"project":{"id":9,"projectNumber":56789,"name":"Project 9","startDate":"2020-10-01","endDate":"2021-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":35.0,"currentBookedMonths":30.0,"remainingBookedMonths":5.0,"numberOfEmployees":3},"employeeBookedMonths":5.0},
{"id":13,"project":{"id":8,"projectNumber":54321,"name":"Project 8","startDate":"2020-05-01","endDate":"2022-06-31","projectLengthInMonths":40.0,"currentBookedMonths":32.0,"remainingBookedMonths":8.0,"numberOfEmployees":4},"employeeBookedMonths":6.6}]},

{"id":3,"name":"John Smith","contractedFrom":"2022-06-01","contractedTo":"2022-12-30","employeeProjects":[
{"id":12,"project":{"id":1,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 1","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":2.5}]}];
```

and this is the chart

```
const labels = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  result.push(item.name);
  return result;
}, []);

const randomColorGenerator = function () {
  return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
};

const projects = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  item.employeeProjects.forEach(function(prj){
    const prjId = prj.project.id;
    if (!result[prjId]) {
      result[prjId] = {
        label: prj.project.name,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: randomColorGenerator()
      };
    }
  });
  return result;
}, {});

listEmployees.forEach(function(item) {
  for (const prjId of Object.keys(projects)) {
    const prj = projects[prjId];
    const empPrj = item.employeeProjects.filter(el => el.project.id === prjId);
    if (empPrj.length) {
      prj.data.push(empPrj[0].employeeBookedMonths);
    } else {
      prj.data.push(0);
    }
  }
});


const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: Object.values(projects)
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: so, this is javascript, not java?

Comment: How does this relate to `spring-boot`? Or `json`? (please read the usage description).

Comment: Sorry but Im using Spring-boot and java, what more can I say. Am I not passing json to the chartJs code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here:

```
const empPrj = item.employeeProjects.filter(el => el.project.id === prjId);
```

because you are comparing a string with a number.

Change it in

```
const empPrj = item.employeeProjects.filter(el => el.project.id === parseFloat(prjId));
```

and it should work. See snippet.

```js
var listEmployees = [
{"id":1,"name":"Bill Turner","contractedFrom":"2022-09-01","contractedTo":"2022-10-30",
"employeeProjects":[
{"id":14,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 7","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":7.7},
{"id":2,"project":{"id":6,"projectNumber":66666,"name":"Project 6","startDate":"2020-10-01","endDate":"2021-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":35.0,"currentBookedMonths":60.0,"remainingBookedMonths":6.0,"numberOfEmployees":6},"employeeBookedMonths":6.0},
{"id":7,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 7","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":8.0},
{"id":5,"project":{"id":9,"projectNumber":56789,"name":"Project 9","startDate":"2020-10-01","endDate":"2021-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":35.0,"currentBookedMonths":30.0,"remainingBookedMonths":5.0,"numberOfEmployees":3},"employeeBookedMonths":8.0},
{"id":15,"project":{"id":8,"projectNumber":54321,"name":"Project 8","startDate":"2020-05-01","endDate":"2022-06-31","projectLengthInMonths":40.0,"currentBookedMonths":32.0,"remainingBookedMonths":8.0,"numberOfEmployees":4},"employeeBookedMonths":8.8}]},

{"id":2,"name":"Kate Miller","contractedFrom":"2022-01-01","contractedTo":"2022-05-30",
"employeeProjects":[
{"id":3,"project":{"id":4,"projectNumber":44444,"name":"Project 4","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":40.0,"remainingBookedMonths":4.0,"numberOfEmployees":4},"employeeBookedMonths":14.0},
{"id":6,"project":{"id":7,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 7","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":5.0},
{"id":8,"project":{"id":9,"projectNumber":56789,"name":"Project 9","startDate":"2020-10-01","endDate":"2021-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":35.0,"currentBookedMonths":30.0,"remainingBookedMonths":5.0,"numberOfEmployees":3},"employeeBookedMonths":5.0},
{"id":13,"project":{"id":8,"projectNumber":54321,"name":"Project 8","startDate":"2020-05-01","endDate":"2022-06-31","projectLengthInMonths":40.0,"currentBookedMonths":32.0,"remainingBookedMonths":8.0,"numberOfEmployees":4},"employeeBookedMonths":6.6}]},

{"id":3,"name":"John Smith","contractedFrom":"2022-06-01","contractedTo":"2022-12-30","employeeProjects":[
{"id":12,"project":{"id":1,"projectNumber":12345,"name":"Project 1","startDate":"2020-01-01","endDate":"2022-12-31","projectLengthInMonths":30.0,"currentBookedMonths":28.0,"remainingBookedMonths":2.0,"numberOfEmployees":5},"employeeBookedMonths":2.5}]}];

const labels = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  result.push(item.name);
  return result;
}, []);

const randomColorGenerator = function () {
  return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
};

const projects = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  item.employeeProjects.forEach(function(prj){
    const prjId = prj.project.id;
    if (!result[prjId]) {
      result[prjId] = {
        label: prj.project.name,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: randomColorGenerator()
      };
    }
  });
  return result;
}, {});

listEmployees.forEach(function(item) {
  for (const prjId of Object.keys(projects)) {
    const prj = projects[prjId];
    const empPrj = item.employeeProjects.filter(el => el.project.id === parseFloat(prjId));
    if (empPrj.length) {
      prj.data.push(empPrj[0].employeeBookedMonths);
    } else {
      prj.data.push(0);
    }
  }
});

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: Object.values(projects)
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
  backgroundColor: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```