# Loop through a list of employees and their projects and display their months spent in a bar chart

Tags: javascript, chart.js, bar-chart

This is a continuation from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73641695/chartjs-stacked-bar-graph-with-foreach-for-labels) and [user2057925](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2057925/user2057925) was super awesome helping me out and also gives a good explanation. However, since my javascript is still very basic compared to what user2057925 had done before I've found an issue and have no idea how to fix.

So the bar chart works great but if an employee has 2 different chunks of time for a project in a given year, only the first (i'm assuming) gets rendered in the stacked bar, but not the second. I've got screen shots showing the issue.

Controller

```
@GetMapping("/chart")
    public String viewChartPage(Model model) {
//      List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployees();
        ChartYear year = new ChartYear("2023");
        List<Employee> employees = employeeService.getAllEmployeesByEmployeeProjectStartDate(year);
        List<String> yearList = employeeProjectService.findAllStartAndEndDatesByYear();
        List<Project> projects = projectService.getAListOfProjectsAndTheirPersonMonthsByYear(year);
        model.addAttribute("employees", employees);
        model.addAttribute("projects", projects);
        model.addAttribute("yearList", yearList);
        model.addAttribute("currentYear", Year.now());
        return "chart.html";
    }
```

The chart

```
const labels = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  result.push(item.name);
  return result;
}, []);

const randomColorGenerator = function () {
  return '#' + (Math.random().toString(16) + '0000000').slice(2, 8);
};

const projects = listEmployees.reduce(function(result, item) {
  item.employeeProjects.forEach(function(prj){
    const prjId = prj.project.id;
    if (!result[prjId]) {
      result[prjId] = {
        label: prj.project.name,
        data: [],
        backgroundColor: randomColorGenerator()
      };
    }
  });
  return result;
}, {});

listEmployees.forEach(function(item) {
  for (const prjId of Object.keys(projects)) {
    const prj = projects[prjId];
    const empPrj = item.employeeProjects.filter(el => el.project.id === parseFloat(prjId));
    if (empPrj.length) {
      prj.data.push(empPrj[0].employeeBookedMonths);
    } else {
      prj.data.push(0);
    }
  }
});

const horizontalArbitraryLine = {
    id: 'horizontalArbitraryLine',
    beforeDraw(chart, args, options) {
        const {ctx, chartArea: {top, right, bottom, left, width, height}, scales:
        {x, y} } = chart;
        ctx.save();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
        ctx.strokeRect(left, y.getPixelForValue(12), width, 1);

        console.log(y.getPixelForValue(3))
    }
};

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: Object.values(projects)
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      x: {
        stacked: true
      },
      y: {
        stacked: true
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [horizontalArbitraryLine]
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="d-flex">
            <h2>Chart for [[${currentYear}]]</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex">
            <div id="selectYear" class="p-2">
                <p>Select Sheet Year:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="p-2">
                <form th:action="@{/ines/chart}" th:object="${chartYear}" method="post">
                    <select class="form-control" id="year" name="year" onchange="this.form.submit()">
                        <option></option>
                        <option th:each="year : ${yearList}" th:value="${year}"
                                th:text="${year}" th:selected="${year == currentYear}">

                        </option>
                    </select>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="myChartDiv">
            <canvas id="myChart" width="900" height="600"></canvas>
        </div>

    <div>
        <canvas id="myBarChart"></canvas>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 800px;
  max-height: 600px;
}

#year {
    width: 85px;
    height: 35px;
}
```

Data

```
[Employee{id=7, name='Luke Sky', contractedFrom='2022-01-15', contractedTo='2025-04-30', employeeProjects=[EmployeeProject{id=24, project=Project{id=1, projectNumber=12345, name='Test Project', startDate='2022-02-01', endDate='2024-08-28', projectLengthInMonths=31.0, currentBookedMonths=32.5, remainingBookedMonths=-30.5, numberOfEmployees=0, comment='31 months'}, employeeBookedMonths=1.0, employeeProjectStartDate=2023-01-01, employeeProjectEndDate=2023-01-31, projectName='Test Project'}, EmployeeProject{id=25, project=Project{id=2, projectNumber=54321, name='Test Project 2', startDate='2021-12-01', endDate='2023-02-28', projectLengthInMonths=15.0, currentBookedMonths=19.5, remainingBookedMonths=-16.5, numberOfEmployees=0, comment='Comment 15 months'}, employeeBookedMonths=0.5, employeeProjectStartDate=2023-04-01, employeeProjectEndDate=2023-04-14, projectName='Test Project 2'}, EmployeeProject{id=27, project=Project{id=1, projectNumber=12345, name='Test Project', startDate='2022-02-01', endDate='2024-08-28', projectLengthInMonths=31.0, currentBookedMonths=32.5, remainingBookedMonths=-30.5, numberOfEmployees=0, comment='31 months'}, employeeBookedMonths=6.5, employeeProjectStartDate=2023-04-15, employeeProjectEndDate=2023-10-31, projectName='Test Project'}, EmployeeProject{id=26, project=Project{id=3, projectNumber=2468, name='Test Project 3', startDate='2022-02-01', endDate='2025-04-30', projectLengthInMonths=39.0, currentBookedMonths=45.0, remainingBookedMonths=-42.0, numberOfEmployees=0, comment='Comment 39 months'}, employeeBookedMonths=1.5, employeeProjectStartDate=2023-11-15, employeeProjectEndDate=2023-12-31, projectName='Test Project 3'}], projectIds=null, startDates=null, endDates=null}]
```

So you can see Luke Sky has only 3 staked bars on the far right, but there is 4 in the console. The 6.5 is missing. The light pink is 0.5, dark pink is 1.5 and green is 1. All 4 are for "Test Project".

[image]

Am I right in assuming it has something to do with the `prj.data.push(empPrj[0].employeeBookedMonths);` part, as it only gets the first employeeProjectBookedMonths for that project? So how do we include both parts? Thanks in advance.

more data screen shot
[image]

Comment: Could you please include sufficient (relevant "*[mcve]*") code to allow us to recreate the problem you show, I assume that you have some CSS and HTML?

Comment: So I added more, but there is a link to my first question above (also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73641695/chartjs-stacked-bar-graph-with-foreach-for-labels) there is also a working code pen (here: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/BaxjwWM)